# Training PCA on BERT word embedding: entire training dataset or each document?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, bert

I want to reduce the dimensionality of the BERT word embedding to, let's say, 50 dimensions. I am trying with PCA. I will use that for the document classification task.

Now for training  PCA, should I train on the entire dataset by using all the word vectors from the entire data set at once that is:

```
pca.fit_transform([all_the_word_vectors_of_the_dataset])
```

or word vectors per document, that is:

```
for document in train_dataset:
    pca.fit_transform([word_vectors_of_current_document])
```